# How to use QPainter outside of the display class?

Tags: c++, qt

In the display class there is a paint event function:

```
    void DisplayWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    // write code to paint pixels...

}
```

my question is how to use this paintEvent function outside of the display class or alternative way to paint from outside the display class.

I've tried using DisplayWindow.PaintEvent() but cant seem to get it to work because of the arguments.

Comment: What are your intentions to doing such things? Normally it's not needed to do such things

Comment: I'm trying to simulate particles splitting into other particles, and have done multi threading for particle reaction. so every time it reacts, it creates a new instance of reaction depending on how many daughter particles there are. Cause of this i don't know how to get the components for each particle. Hence, thought it'd be easier to just paint it while the reaction happens(in the reaction class).